# Output list data in one line

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing, output

the problem is that i cannot output all the data in one line, `lettergrade(float(mylist[2]))` and even a simple string like `"hello"` is always on the next line

`lettergrade` is just a simple function that returns a string

```
print("Student Name\t\tFinal Grade\t\tLetter Grade")
mylist = indata.split(",")
print(mylist[0] + " " + mylist[1] + "\t\t" + mylist[2] + "\t\t" + lettergrade(float(mylist[2])))
```

mylist looks like

```
['Johnson', 'Abby', '95.6\n']
['Smith', 'Frank', '91.3\n']
['Carson', 'Jack', '89.1\n']
['Wells', 'Orson', '87.9\n']
```

**Output I get**

```
Student Name            Final Grade             Letter Grade
Johnson Abby            95.6
                A
Smith Frank             91.3
                A
Carson Jack             89.1
                B
```

**Expected output**

```
Student Name            Final Grade             Letter Grade
Johnson Abby            95.6                    A
Smith Frank             91.3                    A           
Carson Jack             89.1                    B
```

Comment: Remove the `\n` from `mylist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\n stands for a line break, you should remove it:

```
mylist = indata.replace('\n', '').split(",")
```

Comment: I was reading CSV file where it was data in lines and I didn't even notice this \n stacked with the grade, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `\n` from the list :

```
['Johnson', 'Abby', '95.6']
['Smith', 'Frank', '91.3']
['Carson', 'Jack', '89.1']
['Wells', 'Orson', '87.9']
```